# Where to find good worksheets for balancing chemical equations

Tags: stoichiometry

I am preparing for the Chemistry SAT in a couple of weeks. I am looking for worksheets like [this](https://content.lessonplanet.com/resources/previews/original/balancing-chemical-equations-worksheet-worksheet.jpg?1414262231) that will give me practice balancing complex chemical equations with lots of compounds. Is there any website where I can find such questions in bulk? (And also, check my answers?) Thanks.

Comment: Textbooks and Khan Academy....